Cost and space effective isolated sensor for low ac currents
I am working on a product where I need to measure small ac current (around 2 mA). The image below shows the wiring:

There is a power supply that powers up a variable power load (this is user controlled). When the load is off, there will be a small current through the sensor because of the standby power of the power supply. When the load is powered up, the current will rise but at lower power settings, the current rise won't be too high. For ex - 1 W @ 220 VAC means 4.5 mA and 5 W (plus additional 1 W) leads to 27 mA. I need to be able to differentiate if the load is on or off.
I am trying ACS712 hall effect sensor but the resolution is not great. I can try and add some amplifier circuit but would like a solution that doesn't need a lot of PCB area. Is there a better way to do this?

What sort of accuracy is needed?

At a bare minimum, I should be able to differentiate between a current difference of 4 mA. so resolution should be at least this much. Accuracy wise, maybe 10 % error shouldn't be a deal breaker.
